# Non-fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException Unable to resolve host "mysite.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I'm having a lot of entries in my crashLytics reports :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "mobile.site.com": No address associated with hostname
       at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
       at com.spmkt.mobile.action.FormDAO.uploadFormsWithoutPics(SourceFile:70)
       at com.spmkt.mobile.action.FormDAO.uploadFormsWithPics(SourceFile:171)
       at com.spmkt.mobile.BaseActivity.sync_total(SourceFile:274)
       at com.spmkt.mobile.BaseActivity$1.run(SourceFile:170)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I guess it appears when my server is down, or when android detect internet connection, but quality is so bad that it can't connect.

Is it posible to prevent this kind of exceptions???

Comment: are you forgetting to add `http://` at beginning of your URL?

Comment: no, I include http:// and it happens randomly, sometimes I have a peek

Comment: Sounds like the connection is so bad that the answer to the DNS request is lost in transit.  Check that the DNS entry does not accidnetially have a short timeout period so the lookup has to be repeated.

Comment: Have you added the internet permission?

Comment: @user3249477 Yes, in general, it is working. I just have 213 warning since 1 month

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can you please give me more details???

Answer (score 0):

use a previous versions of lib (.jar) file .in async-http-1.4.9 gives the same error .but with version 1.4.7 code works fine

Answer (score -1):

You can use try-catch block around the your code.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html